# How to NOT skip the null value which gets skipped automatically by Cursor.moveToNext()?

Tags: android, database, cursor

I found that `Cursor.moveToNext()` will automatically skip the null values instead of giving `ArrayList` a NULL value or something.

How can I know the value which cursor pointed has nothing ?

This is part of my code:

```
    while(emails.moveToNext() ) //"emails" is a cursor
    {     
      //if( emails point to null value ){
        //do something
      }
      email.add(emails.getString(emails.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Email.DATA)));

    }
```

Please help to solve my question. thx!

Comment: My problem is mainly on "do not skip the null value" but not "check the whole cursor is empty".  Maybe it is two distinct situation?

Comment: `moveToNext()` simply updates the internal current-row index in the `Cursor`. It does not "skip the null value". The current-row index is an `int` and cannot be `null`. A row itself cannot be null; column values for a row could be `null`. Please explain, in **much greater detail**, what your symptoms are.